# Can I access the intermediate C code generated by BCC (BPF Compiler Collection)?

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I'm developing eBPF programs for kernel tracing using BCC. Once I got the following error message when running my code:

```
/virtual/main.c:16:36: error: member reference type 'struct Qdisc *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
    bpf_trace_printk("%ld\n", qdisc.limit);    
                              ~~~~~^
```

I know what is wrong with my code, and it's easy to correct. But I notice there's a file called `/virtual/main.c`. I guess BCC transforms my original C code, which is passed to the `BPF` object in Python, to intermediate C code which is stored in a file called `/virtual/main.c`. Then the intermediate C code is compiled to BPF byte code by `Clang` and `LLVM`, and the BPF code is finally hooked into the kernel.

I wonder if my guess is correct. If it is, is there any way that I can see the intermediate code which is stored in `/virtual/main.c`? I want to know what changes is made by BCC to my original code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know about `BCC` but in `GCC` you can do it by ```gcc main.c -E```

Comment: By the way to access members of a pointer you have to use `->` instead of `.`

Comment: @Darth-CodeX The `BCC` here refers to [BPF Compiler Collection](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc). It's a toolkit to develope eBPF programs instead of a C compiler like `GCC`. Actually `BCC` embeds `Clang` to compile C programs to eBPF bytecode. Maybe you misinterpret it as `Bruce's C compiler`. Still, thanks for your anwser :)

Comment: I really didn't knew about `BCC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell bcc to dump the rewritten C code by passing [`DEBUG_PREPROCESSOR`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/3b5b686a4a9781aee856b77ce7cf352281994e54/src/python/bcc/__init__.py#L55-L56) to the `BPF()` call.

```
BPF(..., debug=DEBUG_PREPROCESSOR)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can see the rewritten C code in the program's output :)